# Show ads related to only food category in Admob

Tags: android, admob

I am developing an Android app in which I want to show the ads only related to food products using the Admob. But I am not sure whether it is possible.

I tried to add restriction to the ads currently showing in my app. But as I am only in the development mode of the application I can't test the filters on the application.

I tried searching for the list of the general category of ads, but unable to find the list. Can someone help me with my question?

Answer (score 3):

You Can Block or Add Advertisements from Specific Category within Admob console.

-Login to Admob -> Select App you want to update

-Select Allow & Blocked Ads ( As shown below ) and select category Food as allowed and block all other categories.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This will help me.

Comment: Just to be clear, while there's nothing wrong with what you're doing, severely limiting the types of ads that can show in your app will mean fewer advertisers competing for your traffic. That will likely have a negative effect on your revenue.

Answer (score 0):

**2023:**

- Select apps on the let panel
- Select your app
- Click `Blocking controls`
- Click `General categories` or `Sensitive categories`

`General categories` contains all possible ad categories(afaik), and `Sensitive categories` contains only few special categories that Admob finds sensitive, like drugs or alcohol.

[image: 1]